# ConnectionString in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, adoconnection

I'm trying to set the ConnectionString for a ADOConnection on start.
Currently I'm using this code:

```
ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\x.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;';
```

Only problem is, I get a "EOLeException with message 'Authentication Failed' when I compile (as well as Access Violation). I'm sure it can't be that difficult, since the connection string is copied straight out of the object inspector (which works perfect when entered normally in object inspector.).
My code currently resides on FormCreate.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your code is in `FormCreate`, where is the `ADOConnection`? Is it on the same form as the code? Is it in a separate datamodule? You're giving almost no information to work with here.

Comment: Are you sure you get the EOLEException and the Access Violation during compile?  Or does it occur at runtime?

Comment: @Ken, Sorry, should have specified. ADOConnection is on the same form.

Comment: @Gamecat. It happens as soon as I press run.

Comment: I've just tested your case and I haven't found any problems. I tried it with a component placed at the form and also dynamically creating it in the `FormCreate` event, with same (positive) result. My guess is that you have additional code that is causing your problem. Do you have any events assigned on the `ADOConnection1`? Did you place component on the form or you create it dynamically?

Comment: I'm guessing that this `TADOConnection` component has another connection string already set in design-time, and its `Connected` property set to `True`, therefore it's attempting to connect to an invalid connection string, which in turn causes haywire before your code even has a chance to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your ADOConnection is in a datamodule along with your other dataset components, you will see an Access Violation on connect if the MainForm is created **before** your datamodule.

This maybe not be the problem but it's easy to check.

To resolve go to the menu Project|Options and select 'Form' in the list. The 'Auto-create Forms' listbox gives the forms created on program load, and the order in which they are created.  Select the datamodule entry and drag it to the top of the list.

Good luck.

Comment: That did it! Only problem is, it shows my datamodule and not my mainform (this is understandable, since logically I start the one before the other). I tried adding hiding the datamodule and showing the main form on my datamodule formcreate, but I get a access violation. What can I do to get the datamodule to create first, but never show.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. I just had to keep my MainForm as being created first and then I just added the connectionstring on my datamodule create. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I'm a little confused. In the comment to your original answer, when I asked if you were using a datamodule you said **no**, that the ADOConnection was on the same form. I answered using that information, but you accept the answer that refers to your **using** a datamodule and not creating it first. ????

Answer (score 2):

If it's happening when you press run, it's happening at **runtime**, not compile-time. You're still providing very little information to use to try and help you.

Make sure you have debugging turned on (Project|Options|Compiler, check the debugging options). Set a breakpoint on the line that causes the exception. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to run your app. When the breakpoint occurs, put your mouse pointer over the `ADOConnection1` variable. What does it tell you? Most likely, that the variable is `nil`, which means it hasn't been created yet.

You should avoid doing anything you don't have to in the `FormCreate` event. Anything that accesses items on the form should be done in `FormShow` instead, so that the form has time to be fully created first.